# How to make PHP Update MySQL Table Form display all Rows of Data

Tags: php, html, mysql

I am trying to make this PHP Update Form display all of my row data from the mysql table. While it does work and update my table, I would like it to display each employee rather than having to search up an employee number in order to edit. Basically I would like it to show an array of employees with edit inputs for each, instead of having to search for each one. I am asking this because I have searched vastly across the web and have found no solutions to my appeal.

Any help will be greatly appreciated.

Thank you

PHP Code:

```
<html>
<head>
<title>Update a Record in MySQL Database</title>
</head>
<body>

<?php
if(isset($_POST['update']))
{
$dbhost = '';
$dbuser = '';
$dbpass = '';
$conn = mysql_connect($dbhost, $dbuser, $dbpass);
if(! $conn )
{
  die('Could not connect: ' . mysql_error());
}

$emp_id = $_POST['emp_id'];
$emp_salary = $_POST['emp_salary'];

$sql = "UPDATE employee ".
       "SET emp_salary = $emp_salary ".
       "WHERE emp_id = $emp_id" ;

mysql_select_db('');
$retval = mysql_query( $sql, $conn );
if(! $retval )
{
  die('Could not update data: ' . mysql_error());
}
echo "Updated data successfully\n";
mysql_close($conn);
}
else
{
?>
<form method="post" action="<?php $_PHP_SELF ?>">
<table width="400" border="0" cellspacing="1" cellpadding="2">
<tr>
<td width="100">Employee ID</td>
<td><input name="emp_id" type="text" id="emp_id"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100">Employee Salary</td>
<td><input name="emp_salary" type="text" id="emp_salary"></td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td> </td>
</tr>
<tr>
<td width="100"> </td>
<td>
<input name="update" type="submit" id="update" value="Update">
</td>
</tr>
</table>
</form>
<?php
}
?>
</body>
</html>
```

Comment: So what you want is to deploy a web form which shows all employees and the user can click or edit a given employee?

Comment: Yes in theory a web form for each employee to edit their salary. I prefer it to be all on the one page. I want to allow the user to edit a given employee's salary.

Comment: It's a good feature to deploy all employees,  if there are less than, say 20.  If there are more,  maybe you should allow user to look for categorized data for example income ranges.  Also it's not a good idea to update all employees data because user just wants to update one. My suggestion is to allow user to edit a given employee,  thus redirecting to a just this employee form,  where can be updated.

Comment: Maybe, it will make sense for you to make a table of all employees (paginated and ordered), put an 'edit' link beside each row. When this 'edit' link is clicked it takes you to the form already filled with the previous information.

Comment: How would you make the link from the table's selected employee go to the employees edit page? I have heard of that before but I am unclear on what the link/code would be. A good idea I just had is when a user clicks that employee to edit in the table and below the table would be a form that becomes suited to that selected employee to edit.

Answer (score 0):

Try to add your sql under form to udpate table.
make var_dump to see if you receive values of employer id ad salary.

Answer (score 0):

Do you want a drop-down menu displaying each employee and then allow the user to enter a new salary for that employee? For that, you could do something like this:

```
echo "<select name='employee'>";
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees");
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
 $id = $row['emp_id'];
 echo "<option value='$id'>$id</option>";
}
echo "<input type='text' name='salary'>
echo "</select>";
```

Forgive me if I misunderstood.

Comment: It would be nice. I am thinking of having the input form for the salary what it is currently for that employee. This would allow the user to see what it is now and what he/she would like it to be. I am not sure if your suggestion would allow that to be possible.

Answer (score 0):

So you want to display the employee's current salary along with the form asking for the user to input a new one? If so, try something like this:

```
$employee = $_POST['employee']; // Or however you're retrieving the current employee the user is editing
$query = mysql_query("SELECT * FROM employees WHERE username='$employee'");

echo "<form action='FILENAME.PHP' method='post'>";
while($row = mysql_fetch_assoc($query)) {
    $salary = $row['emp_salary'];
    echo "Current salary: $salary <br />";
}

echo "<input type='text' name='salary'>";
```

Comment: My problem is that I do not know how to retrieve the employees. I want every employee and their salary in the table to be listed on the page, and to allow the user to edit each employee's salary that is listed on the page.